# Is there a way to assign the "rest" of the items in a list to the final variable in multiple assignment in python?

Tags: python

In ruby I can do something like:

```
key, *rest = ["key1", 1, 2, 3]
```

and the result will be:

```
key = "key1"
rest = [1, 2, 3]
```

Is there a way to do the same in python?

Comment: In python3.x this would work

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
key,rest = my_list[0],my_list[1:]
```

is as close as you can get I think (in Python <= 2.7). In Python 3 your code works as is.